# iCloud Private Relay turned on but not working

Tags: macos, icloud, wifi, privacy

On my Mac I have iCloud Private relay turned on (both on the iCloud settings and for the wifi network), but my IP address doesn't change. It changed on my iPhone and iPad on the same network, but not for my Mac. I tried rebooting and removing and re-adding the wifi network, but the problem remains. Why isn't iCloud private relay working on my Mac?

Comment: What are you using to check your IP on your Mac? (For example: keep in mind that iCloud Private Relay will work with Safari but not 3rd party browsers such as FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: Do you have any kind of VPN running, even some ostensibly DNS-based privacy products? Those can interfere with the QUIC protocol that Private Relay uses.

Comment: Thanks for getting my on the right track. It was AdGuard, they have a KB on how to fix it: https://kb.adguard.com/en/macos/solving-problems/icloud-private-relay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if Content and Privacy Restrictions are enabled under Screen Time, iCloud Private Relay will not work. This only applies to macOS. You can enable both on iOS. I've submitted feedback to Apple on this issue.

(AdGuard also had been causing an issue. But even after switching to the Safari Extension version of their app, I still had the issue.)